# Access cookie with C (CGI)

Tags: c, web, backend, cgi

I am entirely confused right now. I just cannot find a solution on how i can access cookies purely with C(CGI) without javascript. Is this even possible? Is there anyway i can pass cookie data to stdin or something else so my programs can access it?

I need to do this for authentication purposes, i need to know what user is currently logging out so i can forbid him access to some pages until he logs in again.

My pages are dynamically generated without javascript.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Cookies from the client will be in the `HTTP_COOKIE` environment variable. You send cookies to the client with the `Set-Cookie:` header. This is all in the CGI specification.

Comment: wow... i just tried that.. thank you very much, i searched for cgi env variables but sites that i looked up for info did not show me HTTP_COOKIE var.. I should really look up official documentation.

Comment: CGI turns all the request headers into environment variables by adding `HTTP_`. So the `Cookie` header becomes `HTTP_COOKIE`.